# Getting descending totals while traversing an object

Tags: php, arrays

I'm traversing an array/object, with variable row count, where one of the params is numberic. The array is ordered so these numbers are descending (highest first)

ex. 75, 54, 46, 31, 25, 22, 22, 13, 8, 7, 2

Now, while going trough the array, I want to build another array ("Totals") based on those numbers.

I want the first value to be the sum of all the numbers, the second value to be the sum of the second through the last number, the third value to be the sum of the third through the last number, etc

So, the result of the example above would be:

```
$totals[1] = 305
$totals[2] = 230
$totals[3] = 176
$totals[4] = 130
$totals[5] = 99
```

...
etc

Since the key for the source object is not incremental, this needs to be done in the for/while loop.

I can do this with a billion if/+= statements using a counter in nested loops, but it wouldn't be very efficient/dynamic. I'm sure theres a simple way to do it. I just can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Really easy to do – if you just reverse your data array, sum up those reversed values while looping over them and put them into your $totals array, and then reverse that again:

```
$data = array(75, 54, 46, 31, 25, 22, 22, 13, 8, 7, 2);
$data_rev = array_reverse($data);

$totals = array();
$sub_total = 0;

foreach($data_rev as $val) {
  $sub_total += $val;
  $totals[] = $sub_total;
}
$totals = array_reverse($totals);
print_r($totals);
```

($totals is numbered starting with 0 here, not 1 as in your example code – indexes starting at 0 is the common case, so I guess that should do for whatever you want.)

Of course you don’t need to actually reverse the array, you can also simply use a `for` loop to go through it backwards (assuming it is simply numerically indexed, starting at 0 and no “holes” in the index):

```
for($i = count($data)-1; $i >=0; --$i) {
  $sub_total += $data[$i];
  $totals[] = $sub_total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I cant really go through the initial loop backwards because its actually a complex object that has to be processed in the originally sorted order. So, regardless of which method I use, I guess I will have to create a new array of just the values during the first loop - and then go from there. I'll have to test both methods (your's and Jordi's (below)) to see which one is more efficient. Though I'm guessing the difference would be insignificant on 5 - 10 rows :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add a second (clone) of the total array. Like this:

```
<?php

$total = 0;
$sortedarray = rsort($totals);

$tmptotal = $sortedarray;

foreach($sortedarray AS $key => $value) {
    $total += array_sum($tmptotal);
    unset($tmptotal[$key]);
}

echo $total;
```

Comment: Ahhh! array_sum...unset Thanks. But why would I want to rsort the array? Wouldnt I want to unset the first/largest value before each array_sum?

Comment: rsort will sort your array from high to low.

Comment: My bad. I was thinking rsort was "reverse the order of" not "sort in descending order". It should be called "dsort" :) As they are already in descending order, I probably dont need to do the rsort anyway. Thanks again!